# Getting Error: Element type is invalid: when I'm using SVG icon

Tags: react-native, svg

I am Getting Error: Element type is invalid: when I'm using SVG icons, when i'm importing like below. Please help me to resolve the issue.

Here you can find my error and code.

```
import GmailIcon from '../../assets/SVG/Gmail.svg';

  const DetailsList = () => {
    return (
      <View style={styles.detailContainer}>
        <View style={styles.listContainer}>
          <GmailIcon width={moderateScale(20)} height={moderateScale(20)} />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  };
```

here is my console error

```
 ERROR  Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: number.

Check the render method of `DetailsList`.
```

Comment: did you find a solution ? I have the same issue @Atul Singour